# Allowed and safe characters for ZFS filesystem in FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, mount, zfs

Which characters are allowed and safe for ZFS file system name? Are this characters only ASCII or UTF-8 is supported?

'@' is not allowed because it is reserved for snapshots.

PS: I play with FreeBSD 8.2, 9-RC1 and CURRENT+

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only alphanumeric characters, space*, "-", "_", "." and ":" are accepted for file systems names (and other datasets) under ZFS. The maximum file system name length is 255 characters.

Note that this limitation can easily be "workarounded" by setting a valid directory name as a mount point. The latter can be an unlimited sequence of any character from any Unicode character set and is including "@". Of course, "/" is still forbidden being the path delimiter and "null" is excluded as being the string termination character.

Note that space is not [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36835/gbcpt.html) as allowed but is accepted anyway. I wouldn't recommend using it anyway as it would possibly break tools.

Comment: Thanks, I don't worry about mount points, only about datasets

Comment: Just for clarification: ZFS allows everything in file and directory names, except for `/` and `\0`, correct?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling That is correct, ZFS has no forbidden characters outside both of these delimiters.

Comment: @jlliagre Great, thanks for confirming what I expected.

Comment: Why is this answer marked as the accepted answer?  It is not correct.  Simple proof case:  ```touch file#name``` works just fine, so ```#``` is not a disallowed character as this "answer" would suggest.  Thanks @jilliagre for your answer in the comments.  I'm going to propose that as an answer to the question.  Feel free to propose your own answer and I'll retract mine, if you'd like the points.

Comment: @EdwardNedHarvey I'm afraid you are misunderstanding the OP question. This is not about file names like in your `touch` example but about ZFS file system (a.k.a. datasets) names, i.e. the ones you use with `zfs create pool/filesystemname`.

Comment: Actually, I'm posting a question to zfs development mailing list instead.  Trying to get an authoritative response.

Comment: @EdwardNedHarvey Have a look to http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36835/gbcpt.html which is quite authoritative.

Comment: I'd be pretty surprised if filesystem names had a different set of restrictions than filenames.

Comment: @EdwardNedHarvey Then you are going to be surprised ... Please understand we are talking about ZFS dataset names here.

Comment: @EdwardNedHarvey – `touch /zfs/test/foo\#bar` works just fine for me (with ZFS on Ubuntu). You just have to escape it because the _shell_ would otherwise interpret your `#` as the beginning of a comment. (Also, that's a ZFS _filename_ rather than a ZFS _dataset_ name.)